# JQuery Ajax Call https

Tags: jquery, ajax, https, windows-phone-8, call

I'm working on a windows Phone 8 Project, where I need to perform an Ajax call from Javascript  to **https** link, I had a lot of problems with doing that unlike calling a normal http link, So is this even possible? and if possible, then how? and would it be supported by a wide range of devices browsers?

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you would like to call an https page from a http page?  Also that it works when you use normal http?

I would guess that it is a problem with Access-Control-Allow-Origin not being set on the other server if it does not work with http either.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.mysite.com

Or you could just need to use JSONP if you are trying to retrieve JSON data back.

> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Answer (score 0):

So there are a bunch of problems:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b24f0df7-7b1d-4e2e-922d-66df8a4d3d10/in-windows-phone-8-is-x509-authentication-is-possible-by-using-httpwebrequest

More on:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10660
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13884

long story short, if you don't have a valid certificate...